# Websphere 9 throw random database exception

Tags: java, websphere, ejb, jpa-2.0, openjpa

I am using websphere 9, ejb application . Till now I didn't face any errors. But suddenly after restart the server, the application throwing database persistence exceptions . And it fixes after restart the server. Anyone face such random issues?

Exception
<Openjpa 2.2.3 snapshot fatal general error <,
Org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException DB2 SQL Error SQLCode=-530, SQL state =-23503

I have multiple servers and same code deployed in all servers and this issue only occur in one server and after restart the server the issue gone and again after some days the error came back. How the issue fix after restart the websphere 9?

Comment: Please add the exception(s) and any errors you're seeing in the log to your question.

Comment: I am getting persistence exception in saving , getting dbcode 530. And the  issue is fixing after restart websphere 9.